# Automatic login script with w3m

Tags: bash

I want to make a bash script which is automatic login to a webpage uses w3m (i have to use it) but i dont know how to fill the "fields" (username, password, captcha). Can anyone help with it? //Sorry for my English

Comment: You might want to use http://sachachua.com/blog/2009/11/automating-tedious-wiki-editing-tasks-with-emacs-and-w3m/ as a template on how to automate w3m (through its elisp bindings). Obviously not a bash-based answer, but bash isn't the right tool for every job.

Comment: ...see https://github.com/ecbrown/emacs-w3m for an actively maintained branch of emacs-w3m.